# How to access nested JSON Response in Struts 2 jQuery <sj:select> tag

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, struts2

I'm working on a web application using Struts2 and its jQuery Plugin. My `<sj:select>` tag looks like following and is working very well when I've got a non-nested JSON response:

```xml
<s:url id="remoteurl" namespace="/XYZ" action="ZXY"/>
<sj:select 
href="%{remoteurl}" 
id="abc" 
onChangeTopics="dosomething" 
name="cde" 
list="List" 
label="Customer" />
```

From my controller I get something like the following JSON response using an AJAX call.

```
{"List1":null,"Object":{"List2":null,"Var1":null,"List3":{"8":"a","9":"b","10":"c","14":"d","15":"e"}}
```

In my `<sj:select>` I would like to have `List3`, which is an `Object`. But using the shown tag above with `list=Object.List3` it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure this is JSON response that you get? Could you show data structure from which it is generated?

Comment: Try with `list="object.list3"`.

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: It seems that your JSON is malformed.

Comment: Well it is generated by the framework, so I guess - without having a deep JSon knowhow - that it is correctly formed or at least in the intention of the framework sufficiently well formed.

Comment: Deep know-how... Just count `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because firstly the value `Object.List3` in the list attribute is used to evaluate the OGNL expression, then when failed it's used as a name of JSON array (if a map is used then to the JSON object).

But the tag `<sj:select>` used that value as a root JSON object, it doesn't navigate to the JSON array of JSON object because it didn't use if any object-graph navigation library in JS. To make this working you need to add `root` parameter in the JSON result

```
@Action(value="ZXY", results=@Result(type="json", params = {"root","Object"}))
```

then use the JSON annotation to specify `name` if you want to keep that name

```
@JSON(name = "Object.List3")
public Map<Integer,String> getList3() {
  return list3;
}
```

then JSON string will look like

```
{"List2":null,"Var1":null,"Object.List3":{"8":"a","9":"b","10":"c","14":"d","15":"e"}}
```

the `Map<Integer,String>` instead of `List<Object>` because it corresponds to your JSON string and it's not a list.